# Can I accept offers from universities in other countries before I apply to a German university?

Tags: university

I am currently studying in Singapore and am going to take the A-levels this year. All the university applications for the UK and US take place this year and the results will be out early next year. And they usually have deadlines for you to consider their offer.

However, I am extremely fond of studying in Germany and the results of my applications to German universities will only come in July/August next year. By then all offer deadlines for other universities will have passed and if finally I got rejected by all German universities I will have no place to go...

In this case, is it advisory to take up an offer and then apply to a German university? Would the German universities know that you are already enrolled in other universities?

Many thanks!!!
Sarah

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the German university somehow *knows* that you are enrolled at other foreign universities, but it's generally forbidden to be enrolled at two German universities at the same time. However, it is possible and legal to enlist as guest student ("Zweithörer" or "Gasthörer" in German) while enlisted as full student at another German university. This might apply to non-german universities as well.

Regarding the application deadline: as far as I know the deadlines for normal applications is mid-july for the winter semester and mid-january for the summer semster. Normally, you get the results within 2-3 months.

Comment: "and mid-january for the summer semster" - but then, various majors at some places only start in the winter semester. On the other hand, an extra semester might be required for foreign students to do language exams and the respective preparation courses.